# Partitions for dual boot install Ubuntu with Windows

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-10.04, multi-boot

Following is the layout of the current partitions of my single hard drive viewed from Windows 7:

- C: has Windows 7 system files and my
  personal data;
- Q: for Lenovo recovery;
- SYSTEM_DRV: for Windows boot files;

My goals are:

- to create another partition D: for my
  personal data, and dedicate C: for
  Windows system files and applications only.
- to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. D: will be shared between the two OSes.

My questions are:

1. Is it correct that the free space
   generated from shrinking C: will
   only be able to create an extended
   partition, since there are already 3
   primary partitions? So must D: be
   one logical partition on the
   extended partition, just as the
   partitions for Ubuntu will be? Will this be bad sometime? If yes,
   other better solutions?
2. What are the good utilities to
   accomplish the partition tasks? Can
   Ubuntu installer solely handle them?
   Or better to have some of the jobs
   done in Windows with some
   recommended softwares?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most here recommend [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to manipulate partitions before installing Linux, what I would do is make a full disk image of that hard drive in its present state, all partitions and the MBR, verify the image is good, then delete the Lenovo recovery partition, as it won't be any good after you change the partition structure and install Ubuntu. After the recovery partition is gone you will have more space and can make 2 more primary partitions. If you ever wish to go back to the original partition configuration, just restore the image to the hard drive.

The limit is 4 primary partitions by the way.

Lenovo, HP, Dell and others use custom Master Boot Records, and these will get broken when you modify partitions and install another OS, which means you cannot load the recovery partition using the bios.

.

I like [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/index.html) for full disk images, not free though.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure, are these what you were trying to say: (1) if I dual install Ubuntu, the recovery partition will be of no use any more? (2) if I restore from the recovery disks created from the recovery partition, *all the modification to the partitions* and *all the contents added to them* *after the recovery partition was created at factory* will be gone?

Comment: 1. Yes, 2, Yes, If you use Acronis you can make another disk image of the dual boot. Just be sure to make full disk images, this will get all partitions and the MBR. Acronis has a media builder which makes a boot CD, you can boot from this CD and image the drive from there, save the image to a usb drive, just be sure to use the verify feature after the images are done, be sure it is a good image.

Comment: Thanks! I am curious after changing the partitions and installation of the second OS Ubuntu, if I "ever wish to go back to the original partition configuration", can I use the recovery disks created from the recovery partition instead of using the image of the whole disk?

Comment: @ Tim. yes, the HP recovery discs can wipe the drive and restore it as shipped condition.