# How to verify recovery disks created from recovery partition?

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad, system-recovery, system-repair-disc

For my Lenovo T400 with Windows 7, I created three DVDs from its recovery partition. I was wondering

- if it is better to verify that the
  recovery disks are working and how to? I don't
  want my current system to be 
  overwritten.
- if I can delete the recovery
  partition now and release the space.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have 3 DVDs that you made by imaging the recovery partition? Could you clarify?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/241661/have-i-created-the-recovery-disk-from-recovery-partition-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vmware player to boot from the disks and see if your system is restored to your liking.